# VOLTTRON reinstall master driver agent on 7.0

Tags: python, volttron

On VOLTTRON 8.0 versions that use `platform.driver` I can reinstall the platform.driver with:

`python scripts/install-agent.py -s services/core/PlatformDriverAgent -c services/core/PlatformDriverAgent/config -f --start --enable`

But on VOLTTRON 7.0 versions that use `master_driveragent` how do I reinstall the master driver agent on 7.0?

If I do:
`python scripts/install-agent.py -s services/core/MasterDriverAgent -c master-driver.config -f --start --enable`

This will throw an error:
`ERROR:install-agent.py:Force option specified without a target identity to force.`

And if I leave out the force `-f` this will also throw an error:

```
Stderr:
b'install: error: Agent with VIP ID platform.driver already installed on platform.\n'
NoneType: None
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scripts/install-agent.py", line 387, in <module>
    install_agent(opts, opts.package, opts.config)
  File "scripts/install-agent.py", line 148, in install_agent
    out = execute_command(cmds, env=env, logger=log,
  File "/var/lib/volttron/volttron/platform/agent/utils.py", line 776, in execute_command
    raise RuntimeError()
RuntimeError
```

The current `vctl status` looks like this:

```
(volttron) volttron@volttron:/var/lib/volttron$ vctl status
   AGENT                  IDENTITY                TAG          STATUS          HEALTH
8f actuatoragent-1.0      platform.actuator                    running [1477601] GOOD
e1 bacnet_proxyagent-0.5  platform.bacnet_proxy   bp           running [2023876] GOOD
26 forwarderagent-5.1     platform.historian      fh           running [1548751] GOOD
55 master_driveragent-4.0 platform.driver         md           running [2023877] GOOD
```

Answer (score 0):

The 7.0 install agent script is not aware of the default identity for the agent, so you have to provide it explicitly

add `-i platform.driver`

full install script:

`python scripts/install-agent.py -s services/core/MasterDriverAgent -c master-driver.config -f -i platform.driver --start --enable`